# Building an editable RESTful API

Tags: c#, rest, api

Is it possible to build an API which can be live modified? Let me explain myself.
Imagine that all the lights in my house are managed by Raspberry PIs that send a POST request to the API at "http://192.168.1.2/". The light number one would send to "http://192.168.1.2/light1/hello" `{"state":"off"}`and the answer of the server would be `off`and the light number two would send to "http://192.168.1.2/light2/hello" `{"state":"on"}` and the server answer would be `on`. The API Server would display that light one is off and that light two is on. How can I make an API in which it can edit the responses for a specific light without restarting the whole server? It would be cool to do it in C#, but I would accept a response in any language. Thanks for reading.

Comment: You simply need to store the state somewhere when it changes. When a request that comes in to get the current state, retrieve it from your store and provide it as part of the response. This is just basic server/client web application development. If that sounds too daunting and you don't know where to start, perhaps try some tutorials?

Comment: "edit the responses for a specific light"...you mean change what the code does when you send a particular message? Or change what answer it gives in any particular moment? Presumably the code would go away and look up the correct answer by querying the light itself and return the current status, so that part wouldn't be a problem. That's a very standard thing for an application / API to do (e.g. query a database or other store of data). OTOH If you want to modify the code behaviour, you might not have to restart the server, but you'd certainly have to re-deploy the code files.

Comment: @mason where can I get some tutorials on it please ?

Comment: Asking for tutorials isn't on topic for Stack Overflow. Part of learning to be a developer is learning to use resources available to you, such as search engines.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, I'm not sure I see what the advantage to this architecture would be? In your example, light1 and light2 are entities of type "light", which share a bit property (state).

The typical restful way to do this would be create an endpoint that takes the entity id as part of the path, and send the state along with it as you mentioned. Then the entity source (lights) can be edited without a change to the server code, and you're not exposing potentially important information (i.e. the name of a light), through your endpoint.

Example for posting (toggling light status) would be http://192.168.1.2/light/hello/2 with a body of `{state:on}`, where if done in C#, `hello` would be an action on `LightController`, and `2` would be the `id` parameter of the action:

```
public void Hello(int id, [FromBody] object state)
```

and to GET the state of a light, would be the same method, but use an HttpGet instead of an HttpPost, with no body of course (but still sending an id to get a single light state).

And you'd want to use another endpoint, like `light/all` to get all light statuses.

But no, you can't change endpoints (or any functionality) of a web service without restarting the server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not possible to modify the response for a specific path without restarting the whole server ?

Comment: You misunderstood this @Econo Mix. If you wanted to add something new - for example add new property to lights, `color` - you'd have to restart server. The thing that you want doesn't require server restart.

Server is basically an application. It remembers list of lights and if it is turned on or off. You can ask: what is state of light 1? And it replies on/off. And you can say: change state of light 1 to `off` and the application will remember it. I strongly recommend you to find some Asp.Net REST API tutorials.